# Redireccionar al login en Laravel 5.4 si falla el token

Tags: php, laravel-5

Cuando estoy en la página de **login** por un buen rato sin actividad e intento loguearme, me sale el error **TokenMismatchException** y se que tiene que ver con el **token** que está en el formulario de acceso y que al estar tanto tiempo sin actividad el **token** se vuelve inválido, pero como evito que en lugar de que me muestre el error, simplemente me redireccione al **login**.

**Información del error:**

> TokenMismatchException
>   in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que gestionar el error que provoca el hecho de que el `token` esté "caducado". Esto lo puedes hacer en `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`. En la clase `Handler`, dentro de la función `render` tienes que poner el siguiente código:

```
if ($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException)
   {
      return response()
         ->redirectTo('login')
         ->with('flash_error', 'Mensaje de error que quieras mostrar'));
   }
```

**Aportación de [Edwin Galeano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/85311/edwin-galeano)**

Se debe agregar en la parte superior `use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;` de lo contrario `$exception instanceof TokenMismatchException` sera false

Comment: A tener en cuenta: Se debe agregar en la parte superior **use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;** de lo contrario **$exception instanceof TokenMismatchException** sera false